# Why do you have to specify 2 arguments explicitly to curry :>

Tags: ruby

Consider this, which works fine:

```
:>.to_proc.curry(2)[9][8] #=> true, because 9 > 8
```

However, even though `>` is a binary operator, the above won't work without the arity specified:

```
:>.to_proc.curry[9][8] #=> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

Why aren't the two equivalent?

Note: I specifically want to create the intermediate curried function with one arg supplied, and *then* call then call that with the 2nd arg.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

curry has to know the arity of the proc passed in, right?

```
 :<.to_proc.arity  # => -1
```

Negative values from `arity` are confusing, but basically mean 'variable number of arguments' one way or another.

Compare to:

```
 less_than = lambda {|a, b| a < b}
 less_than.arity # => 2
```

When you create a lambda saying it takes two arguments, it knows it takes two arguments, and will work fine with that style of calling #curry.

```
 less_than.curry[9][8] # => false, no problem!
```

But when you use the symbol #to_proc trick, it's just got a symbol to go on, it has no idea how many arguments it takes. While I don't think `<` is actually an ordinary method in ruby, I think you're right it neccessarily takes two args, the Symbol#to_proc thing is a general purpose method that works on any method name, it has no idea how many args the method should take, so defines the proc with variable arguments.

I don't read C well enough to follow the MRI implementation, but I assume Symbol#to_proc defines a proc with variable arguments. The more typical use of Symbol#to_proc, of course, is for a no-argument methods. You can for instance do this with it if you want:

```
hello_proc = :hello.to_proc
class SomeClass
  def hello(name = nil)
     puts "Hello, #{name}!"
  end
end
obj = SomeClass.new
obj.hello #=> "Hello, !"
obj.hello("jrochkind") #=> "Hello, jrochkind!"
obj.hello("jrochkind", "another")
# => ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments calling `hello` (2 for 1)

hello_proc.call(obj)  # => "Hello, !"
hello_proc.call(obj, "jrochkind") # => "Hello, jrochkind!"
hello_proc.call(obj, "jrochkind", "another")
# => ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments calling `hello` (2 for 1)

hello_proc.call("Some string")
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `hello' for "Some string":String
```

Note I did `hello_proc = :hello.to_proc` before I even defined `SomeClass`. The Symbol#to_proc mechanism creates a variable arity proc, that knows nothing about how or where or on what class it will be called, it creates a proc that can be called on any class at all, and can be used with any number of arguments.

If it *were* defined in ruby instead of C, it would look something like this:

```
class Symbol
  def to_proc
    method_name = self
    proc {|receiver, *other_args|  receiver.send(method_name, *other_args) }
  end
end
```

Comment: I think in your `def to_proc` you should change `lambda` to `proc`.

Comment: okay, I have no idea which it uses and am not sure it would make any difference which one the implementation used (I _think_  not), but if you think so I'll change it!

Comment: It uses `proc`. You can test this by checking `:>.to_proc.lambda?`, which returns `false`.

Comment: I did just say it would look _something_ like that, heh. I think it would function identically if it were lambda or proc, it makes no difference (I think?) but I've edited my example per your request, thanks!

Comment: The pseudo-code made everything come together for me.  Thanks!

Comment: Great answer! FWIW `<`, like most (all?) operators in Ruby *is* a regular method. The left operand is the receiver and the right operand is the argument, i.e. `a < b` is syntactic sugar for `a.<(b)`, or equivalent to `a.send(:<, b)`. But you're exactly right that Ruby has no way of inferring the arity from a symbol (there's nothing stopping a `<` method from taking more than one argument, or zero arguments—`def <(x, y, z)` and `def <()` are both valid).

Comment: The only thing missing from your answer is a mention of `Object#method` and the Method class. I've posted my own answer with that info (but I still think yours should be the accepted answer).

Comment: Jordan: It's interesting, it's defined as a method, and you can call it with `send` (as the `to_proc` implementation ends up doing), but it's also treated weird syntactically. You can't define a `<` that takes more than one arg, and call it like `obj.<(one, two, three)`.  At least I couldn't when I tried it.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is because `Symbol#to_proc` creates a proc with one argument. When turned into a proc, `:>` does not look like:

```
->x, y{...}
```

but it looks like:

```
->x{...}
```

with the requirement of the original single argument of `>` somehow tucked inside the proc body (notice that `>` is not a method that takes two arguments, it is a method called on one receiver with one argument). In fact,

```
:>.to_proc.arity # => -1
->x, y{}.arity # => 2
```

which means that applying `curry` to it without argument would only have a trivial effect; it takes a proc with one parameter, and returns itself. By explicitly specifying `2`, it does something non-trivial. For comparison, consider `join`:

```
:join.to_proc.arity # => -1
:join.to_proc.call(["x", "y"]) # => "xy"
:join.to_proc.curry.call(["x", "y"]) # => "xy"
```

Notice that providing a single argument after Currying `:join` already evaluates the whole method.

Answer (score 3):

@jrochkind's answer does a great job of explaining why `:>.to_proc.curry` doesn't have the behavior you want. I wanted to mention, though, that there's a solution to this part of your question:

> I specifically want to create the intermediate curried function with one arg supplied, and then call then call that with the 2nd arg.

The solution is [`Object#method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-method). Instead of this:

```
nine_is_greater_than = :>.to_proc.curry[9]
nine_is_greater_than[8]
#=> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

...do this:

```
nine_is_greater_than = 9.method(:>)
nine_is_greater_than[8]
# => true
```

`Object#method` returns a [Method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Method.html) object, which acts just like a Proc: it responds to `call`, `[]`, and even (as of Ruby 2.2) `curry`. However, if you need a *real* proc (or want to use `curry` with Ruby < 2.2) you can also call `to_proc` on it (or use `&`, the `to_proc` operator):

```
[ 1, 4, 8, 10, 20, 30 ].map(&nine_is_greater_than)
# => [ true, true, true, false, false, false ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I already knew about this trick, actually, and was mainly interested in understanding how curry works, but I think it's a good answer to have for other people who stumble on this question.